# Recursive regular expression: how to set a mismatch with the string, rather than individual characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

My php code:

```
      $exp = 'zzz<pre>sssss<pre>fff</pre>ff</pre>zzz';     
      \preg_match_all("#<pre>((?>[^(?:<pre>)(?:</pre>)]|(?R))*)</pre>#si", $exp, $matches);

        $i = 0;
        foreach ($matches as $item) {           
            foreach ($item as $elem)
            {
                echo "$i  ", \htmlentities($elem), "<br>";
            }
            $i++;
        }
```

Output:

> 0 `<pre>sssss<pre>fff</pre>ff</pre>`
>
> 1 `sssss<pre>fff</pre>ff`

That is good - regex works and finds nested tags `<pre>`. But I have one problem:

```
[^(?:<pre>)(?:</pre>)]
```

I can set a dismath with charaters `< / p r e >`, but I need to set a dismach with strings `<pre>` and `</pre>`. Therefore, if I add in the original text at least the symbol `p` or `r`, regex do not work as it should.

Example:  `$exp = zzz<pre>ssspss<pre>fff</pre>ff</pre>zzz; // p inside ssspss`

Output

> 0 `<pre>fff</pre>`
>
> 1 `fff`

Tell me, how to build the regular expression to set a mismatch with the string, rather than individual characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you want to use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) instead of the [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated):

```
~<pre>((?>(?!</?pre).|(?R))*)</pre>~si
```

See [test at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/tJ4uE8/1)

Your regex didn't work as expected, because `[^(?:<pre>)(?:</pre>)]` matches any character that is not in the `[^` negated [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). Any that is not one of: `<`,`/`,`p`,`r`,`e`,`)`,`(`,`?`,`:`,`>`

---

*Sidenote*: Regex is not appropriate for parsing arbitrary nested html. Consider [using a parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php).

Comment: Thank you for help and especially for the link to regex101.com